# How to work with Multiple datasource by J2ee7, CDI, DOMA, Glassfish 4

Tags: jakarta-ee

My application must be connect to 2 oracle schemas.
I Use J2ee7 with CDI to inject, DOMA to work in DAO layer and Glasshfish 4 for server.

With 1 shema, in normal I connect to schema as below:

AppConfig:

```
@Singleton
public class AppConfig implements Config {

@Inject
private Dialect _dialect;

@Inject
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/source")
private DataSource _dataSource;

@Override
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return _dataSource;
}

@Override
public Dialect getDialect() {
    return _dialect;
}
}
```

DAO:

```
@Dao(config=AppConfig.class)
@InjectConfig
public interface ITestDao {

@Insert
public int insert(TestDto dto);

@Delete
public int delete(TestDto dto);

@Select
public List<TestDto>searchAll();

}
```

With this code, it's run normally.

But i don't know how to work with multiple oracle schema, each schema is a data source.
Please tell me.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implemets 2 config class.

```java
@Singleton
public class DS1Config implements Config {

    @Inject
    private Dialect _dialect;

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/source1")
    private DataSource _dataSource;

    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return _dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialect getDialect() {
        return _dialect;
    }
}

@Singleton
public class DS2Config implements Config {

    @Inject
    private Dialect _dialect;

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/source2")
    private DataSource _dataSource;

    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return _dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialect getDialect() {
        return _dialect;
    }
}

@Dao(config=DS1Config.class)
@InjectConfig
public interface IFooDao {

    @Insert
    public int insert(FooDto dto);

    @Delete
    public int delete(FooDto dto);

    @Select
    public List<FooDto>searchAll();

}

@Dao(config=DS2Config.class)
@InjectConfig
public interface IBarDao {

    @Insert
    public int insert(BarDto dto);

    @Delete
    public int delete(BarDto dto);

    @Select
    public List<BarDto>searchAll();

}
```